# How to pass phpStan with a customLoginLinkNotification?

Tags: symfony, phpstan

I'm using the login_link ([docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/login_link.html)) to authenticate an user who forgot his password.
Following the docs, I customized the email and I override the htmlTemplate but in real life phpStan stop me saying :
`Call to an undefined method Symfony\Component\Mime\RawMessage::htmlTemplate().`
I'm trying to fix it but I'm stuck :(
Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

The return type hint for `EmailMessage::getMessage()` is `RawMessage`, which in fact has no methode `htmlTemplate()`.

However in this particular case, you are actually getting a `NotificationMail` ([see the related code here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.4/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/LoginLink/LoginLinkNotification.php#L46)) which eventually inherits from the `RawMessage` but implements the `htmlTemplate()` method (or, to be more precises, it inherits from the `TemplatedEmail` which implements said method).

There are a couple of ways to fix this issue with phpstan:

- Check if `$email` is in fact an instance of `NotificationMail`

  ```
   $email = $emailMessage->getMessage();

   if ($email instanceof NotificationMail) {
       $email->htmlTemplate(...);
   }
  ```
- Add an assert which will throw an exception during runtime if `$email` is not a `NotificationMail`

  ```
    $email = $emailMessage->getMessage();

    assert($email instanceof NotificationMail);
    $email->htmlTemplate(...);
  ```
- Add an inline `@var`. Note that [this method is discouraged](https://phpstan.org/writing-php-code/phpdocs-basics#inline-%40var) as per the phpstan documentation. (Thanks to [@Ondřej Mirtes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/565782/ond%C5%99ej-mirtes) for pointing that out)

  ```
    /** @var NotificationMail $email */
    $email = $emailMessage->getMessage();
  ```

Comment: Thank you vey much, I understand better now You fixed my problem :)

Comment: The usage of inline `@var`s is discouraged: https://phpstan.org/writing-php-code/phpdocs-basics#inline-%40var

Comment: @OndřejMirtes thanks for pointing that out. I updated the answer to also include other solutions and adding a note to the `@var` solution.

Comment: @Christoph That’s nice, thanks. What I’m asking myself in cases like this is “what’s the type of $emailMessage and can PHPStan already know that getMessage always returns NotificationMail?”